# Python error in docker - distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python-3.x, docker, gcc, pip, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to install google-cloud-pubsub in a docker image. One of the requirement is to install grpcio. While trying to install grpcio, I get an error like "distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1"

I have also installed these packages -> *pip install --upgrade wheel numpy panda cython six*

Version used : Python 3.6.9 & pip 20.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)

```
        Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/tmp/pip-install-gtay96uw/grpcio/src/python/grpcio/commands.py", line 262, in build_extensions
      build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 195, in build_extensions
      _build_ext.build_ext.build_extensions(self)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 448, in build_extensions
      self._build_extensions_serial()
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 473, in _build_extensions_serial
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 208, in build_extension
      _build_ext.build_extension(self, ext)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 533, in build_extension
      depends=ext.depends)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/ccompiler.py", line 574, in compile
      self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    File "/tmp/pip-install-gtay96uw/grpcio/src/python/grpcio/commands.py", line 246, in new_compile
      pp_opts)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/unixccompiler.py", line 120, in _compile
      raise CompileError(msg)
  distutils.errors.CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

  ----------------------------------------
  **ERROR: Failed building wheel for grpcio
  Running setup.py clean for grpcio**
```

Tried other version of google-cloud-pubsub as well -> 1.5.0, 1.6.1. All ending with the same error.

My Docker file looks like below.

```
### 1. Get Linux
FROM alpine:3.7

### 2. Get Java via the package manager
RUN apk update \
&& apk upgrade \
&& apk add --no-cache bash \
&& apk add --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies unzip \
&& apk add --no-cache curl \
&& apk add --no-cache openjdk8-jre

#### OPTIONAL : 4. SET JAVA_HOME environment variable, uncomment the line below if you need it
ENV JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk"
ENV PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:${PATH}"

RUN which java && java -version
RUN echo $PATH

#FROM python:3.7.5-alpine3.9
### 3. Get Python, PIP
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 \
&& python3 -m ensurepip \
&& pip3 install --upgrade pip setuptools \
&& rm -r /usr/lib/python*/ensurepip && \
if [ ! -e /usr/bin/pip ]; then ln -s pip3 /usr/bin/pip ; fi && \
if [[ ! -e /usr/bin/python ]]; then ln -sf /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python; fi && \
rm -r /root/.cache

RUN apk --update add --no-cache gcc python3-dev musl-dev g++

RUN apk --update add gpgme-dev libc-dev

FROM gcr.io/google.com/cloudsdktool/cloud-sdk:alpine
RUN gcloud components install gsutil bq
```

Comment: Please don't attach screen shots of terminal windows to SO questions.  _Especially_ don't attach screen shots where the error message is dark red on black.  Copy and paste the error messages directly into the question instead.  A [mcve] is also essential: instead of just the error message, your question should also include enough source code (like, for example, your image's Dockerfile) to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks David, done that as suggested.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1 when installing pip packages on alpine docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58629049/error-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-when-installing-pip-packages-on-a)

Comment: hi @SiHa, I have added every package mentioned in the link above. Still the same issue !

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting this problem on alpine linux.

```
apk add python-dev
```

solved with this code.